# Wasm-ld not found after performing brew install wabt

Tags: webassembly

I am trying to use emscripten for which i need the webassembly toolkit something like binaryen however I chose to use wabt. I installed it using `brew install wabt` from which i get commands like `wasm-objdump` but `wasm-ld` is just nowehere to be found. And yes I have installed llvm.

Answer (score 2):

wasm-ld is installed as part of the lld linker packages (e.g. lld-10 on ubuntu). Check to see if you have that package installed. If not, install that, and the wasm-ld binary may appear in /usr/bin.

If you have that installed, there are two possibilities:
1.) The directory containing the binary is not part of your path: check /usr/lib/llvm-10/bin to see if the binary is in there (if llvm-10 is the version you have installed).
2.) The binary is in /usr/bin, but has the version number attached to its name (e.g. wasm-ld-10).

In either case, a temporary solution is to create a symbolic link to the binary in /usr/bin using "ln  wasm-ld"

Comment: sudo apt-get install lld-8  did ot work on my Ubuntu yet.

Answer (score 1):

wasm-ld is part of the llvm project.  It is installed with llvm 8.0 and above by default.

Comment: With LLVM 14, I found this to be not true. You have to install lld separately to get wasm-ld, the llvm installation does not contain it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error in spite of installing llvm, it may have installed it and you may need to add it to your path.  I.e.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/llvm-10/bin
```

for LLVM-10

Also, see the other answers, it appears the answer changes heavily depending on the version as this tool seems to be some sort of hot potato.